# GraphQL Mutation Updating Users Followers with Mongoose/MongodDB - $set is empty error

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I have this mutation set up:

```
followUser: {
  type: UserType,
  args: {
    _id: { type: GraphQLString },
    firebaseUid: { type: GraphQLString },
    following: { type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLString)},
  },
  resolve(parentValue, { firebaseUid, _id, following}) {
    const update = {
      $set: { "following": [firebaseUid] },
      $push: { "following": { firebaseUid } }
    }
    return UserSchema.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id }, 
      update, 
      {new: true, upsert: true}
    )
  }
},
```

I'm trying to add new followers into my graphql user's collection. My user model:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema(
  {
    firebaseUid: String,
    following: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    followers: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

So at first, the user doesn't have any followers, so it won't have that field yet. When user adds someone to their friends list, thats when the field will appear in mongodb. Right now I'm getting this error:

```
"message": "'$set' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$set: {<field>: ...}}",
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing the `$set` correctly.

The UserType

```
const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "User",
  fields: () => ({
    _id: { type: GraphQLString },
    firebaseUid: { type: GraphQLString },
    following: { type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLString) },
    followers: { type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLString) },
    ...
  })
});
```

---

edit:

current mongodb data collection:

```
_id: ObjectId("5e5c24111c9d4400006d0001")
name: "Mr. Smith"
username: "mrsmith"
```

after running the update

```
_id: ObjectId("5e5c24111c9d4400006d0001")
name: "Mr. Smith"
username: "mrsmith"
following: ["fdsaduybfeaf323dfa"] // <-- this gets added
```

Comment: Youre setting and pushing to the same field. Is that intended?

Comment: @als My understanding is that since following isn't in the database yet, I thought I would have to "set" it first, and then "push" new changes to that field? Am I understanding it wrong? I'm not sure if that's what I"m supposed to do

Comment: If you use `$set: { "following": [firebaseUid] }` then `following` should be an array containing `firebaseUid` as its first and only entry.

Comment: @als i updated my post to illustrate the current data, and after the update on what I'm trying to achieve. I thought I needed to `$set: { "following": [firebaseUid] }` because it didn't have an array field yet, and then wanted to push an ID per the `$push`

Comment: If you don't have the array yet you should just use the `$set` without `$push` because if you set with the array `[firebaseUid]` then the created array wont be empty but rather exactly what you provide to the `$set` operator

Comment: But eventually i'll get the $set, then wouldn't I need $push to add to the array later? to keep updating? Or will set just do that for me?

Comment: Actually you're right using only `$push` here is the best option, because it will create the array if it does not exist already. I'm a bit curious as to why you're getting the error you're getting. If i try to run a test like this i get an error about conflicting updates. You should also get rid of the additional `{}` around `firebaseUid`, because otherwise you get an array containing objects like `{'firebaseUid': <some id>}`

Comment: @als when I remove `$set` and just have `$push: { "following": firebaseUid }`, I get this error: `"'$set' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$set: {<field>: ...}}",`

Comment: Hmm maybe we should eliminate the basics: Is the correct resolver being called? Maybe you can log the content of `firebaseUid` to confirm this.

Comment: hmmm, so this is what is getting returned: `Mongoose: users._findAndModify({ _id: ObjectId("5e0e16929fcc7506926cd31336d") }, [], { '$set': {} }, { new: true, upsert: true, remove: false, projection: {} })`

I guess the push isn't there? but why is it not showing, when I console log `firebaseUid` I do get: `lLa2y35c3BTgbjEZbtijlOfzBV313e2`, which is the correct value

Comment: Possibly because the schema says that `following` should be an array of `ObjectId`s and firebase ids are not 12-byte hex strings, so the validation of the update against the schema fails and does the `$set: { }` by default or something. You could try changing the schema to `String` instead of `ObjectId` or turn of strict mode for the model.

Comment: Oh yeah, that works! Thanks! I guess one issue I'm getting is its inserting twice, each time.

Comment: @als i fixed the duplication issue. But thanks for your help! would you want to submit an answer and I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently mongooses validator is rejecting the update. To fix this you need the following:

1. You only need to `$push` since it will automatically create an array if the property does not exist
2. You should remove the extra `{ }` around the `firebaseUid` in the `$push` because otherwise the `following` array will contain objects with a `firebaseUid` property instead of directly containing the Uid (or would if the schema validator allowed it)
3. Mongo `ObjectId`s can only be converted from strings when they are 12-byte hexadecimal, and `firebaseUid` is not, so the schema should be typed to `String` instead of `ObjectId` as the validator will reject the field for update otherwise.